# Configuration File Manager Class

Tags: python, design-patterns, configuration

I have to create code for a "Configuration Manager". The idea is to have a file with all connections strings, paths to another configuration files, data base hostnames, users and passwords, etc. and access to that information with a some sort of configuration manager, to make it uniform across all modules in the code. It even could be a singleton object living in memory during the whole code execution (takes several hours).

I googled and search stackoverflow for something like this, but didn't really find anything useful. I don't need a big explanation or example, just a hint or idea to the direction I should take. 
Also, is it better to have the file in a xml or just an ini formats? The encryption isn't a concern as of now.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: It seems like a possible answer, thanks sr2222! Post it below as an answer if you want, I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) should work.  If you need something more customized then that allows, you'd need to provide more specifications for us to have an idea what to suggest.